# Multiple Join in VB.NET LINQ query?

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am trying to do a multiple join with VB.NET and LINQ and I can do one join just fine, but then it complains when I do 2 joins.  Is there something wrong with my syntax.

This works:

```
Dim dv = (From a In db.A Join d In db.D On a.Id Equals d.Id 
          Where d.Id = 1 Select a.Project).Distinct().ToList
```

This does not work:

```
Dim dv = (From a In db.A Join d In db.D On a.Id Equals d.Id
          Join p in db.P On a.pid Equals p.Id
          Where d.Id = 1 Select a.Project).Distinct().ToList
```

Comment: Please clarify "it complains".

Comment: @Heinzi - When I try to put the second on, intellisense doesn't popup.  I don't really get an error, but I assume something is wrong with the syntax because it doesn't even allow the "On"

Comment: Your code compiles perfectly fine here. Do you get any error when you try to compile it?